# Device compabilities issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, telephony

We uploaded an app where in the first version we added to device capabilities “telephony” to restrict only iPhone devices in the info plist. In the second version we forgot to add “telephony” and we submitted to the App store. Third version we are planning to upload with device capabilities as “telephony” but while submitting to the App Store it shows the warning:

> This bundle is invalid. The key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in the
>   Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application
>   from running on devices that were supported by previous versions.

How can we resolve this issue, if we require the device capability “telephony” for  application lifetime, but due to my mistake on the second version we forgot to add the required device capabilities? What is the solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side question: Does your app really need telephony capabilities, or you just wanted an (artificial) way to limit the installation to iPhone devices?

Comment: yes "telephony" is need because it has to install only in iPhone devices like "whatsapp"

Comment: Your app makes phone calls? Then, you will have to show an alert to the users telling them that some features are only available on phones.

Comment: Apple is mad!!!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same warning when added to device capabilities “healthkit” t in the info plist.

> This bundle is invalid - The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions.

delete Info.plist -> Required device capabilities -> Item -> healthkit，upload again to submit review success.

Comment: Same issue, this solution works for me, by the way, did you passed Apple Store Review? Just submitted, not sure about this.

Comment: Even if you use HealthKit in your app ?

Comment: Wouldn't this get rid of the device capability though?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to fix this error. According to Apple's [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html):

> Depending on how you narrow the devices your app supports, you will
>   get one of two error messages from Xcode when uploading your update to
>   the App Store.
>
> "This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the
>   Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application
>   from running on devices that were supported by previous versions."
>
> When you see this error message, you have added a new constraint,
>   under the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your app's info.plist
>   file.
>
> **Important: Because you can't add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>   restrictions after an app is in the store, be sure to plan ahead by
>   choosing requirements you will be comfortable supporting indefinitely
>   going forward.**

Comment: we planned for to restrict the app only for  iphone devices but during second version because of merge issues "telephony"got removed from the plist and it got submitted (note first version is with "telephony"),my question how they accept the build of second version

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to relax UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities restrictions, but not tighten them. Once restrictions are relaxed they cannot be tightened back again.